# Print text data using blue tooth supported printer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, zebra-printers, thermal-printer

I want to use printer to print data from our android application, can any one suggest me good and simple technique  to print the text data on paper?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess you are to use a Thermal Printer and for that you require a printer SDK from the manufacturer.

Comment: But can u suggest me any link or process to how can I do that..

Comment: Actually there are many hand-held Bluetooth Thermal Printers available in the market. Pick one considering your requirement and then find the printer SDK of it if you are lucky. Otherwise you get to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you vidulaJ for your valuable response..

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use below android documentation to achieve this task but make sure that your printer is Moperia cerified(http://mopria.org/)

1. https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html
2. https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

Thanks

Comment: you can access printer through wifi or through Bluetooth, Moperia is certification for printer who will connect to mobile through common driver